# How to display current year in Flask template?

Tags: python, datetime, templates, flask

I am looking to find out how to output the current year in a Flask template. I know in Django you can use `{% now "Y" %}.`, but is there a Flask equivalent? I have been unable to find anything during my research thus far.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use a [template context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#context-processors) to pass the current date to every template, then render its `year` attribute.

```
from datetime import datetime

@app.context_processor
def inject_now():
    return {'now': datetime.utcnow()}
```

```
{{ now.year }}
```

Or pass the object with `render` if you don't need it in most templates.

```
return render_template('show.html', now=datetime.utcnow())
```

Answer (score 6):

For moment there is [Flask Moment](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Moment). It is powerful like Moment, and easy to use in Flask. To display the year in the user's local time from your Jinja template:

```html
<p>The current year is: {{ moment().format('YYYY') }}.</p>
```

Answer (score -7):

If using Jinja2 is too cumbersome and you are using `Jinja2` in a context of a browser that you can simply use Javascript.

##### Using Simple Javascript

```html
<span id="year"></span>
```

```js
const year = document.querySelector('#year');
if (year) {
    year.innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
}
```

---

##### JavaScript library like moment.js

```html
<script>
document.write(moment("2012-12-31T23:55:13 Z").format('LLLL'));
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend doing this in Jinja for compatibility, not in JS, but if you somehow can't: `<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>` doesn't require a library.